# Default behavior of destructuring assignment without brackets

Tags: javascript

What happens when the brackets are left off on the `LHS` (Left Hand Side) when using the destructuring assignment syntax? For example:

```js
{
    let a,b = [1,2];
    console.log(a, b);
}
{
    let [a,b] = [1,2];
    console.log(a, b);
}
```

If brackets are not included, does it act equivalent to doing:

```
let a=undefined, b=[1,2];
```

Or what exactly occurs when brackets are left off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the brackets are left off on the LHS (Left Hand Side), it would become a variable assignment as you can [declare multiple variables separated by a comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#syntax).

So:

```js
let a,b = [1,2];
```

Is equivalent to:

```js
let a;
let b = [1,2];

console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [declare multiple variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#syntax) with a single `let` by separating them with a comma. So without the brackets you're effectively doing:

```js
let a;
let b = [1, 2];
```